# Tag combinations for Favorites

Tags: support, feature-request

Is is possible to have tag combinations for favorites on this site or regular StackOverflow? What I mean is that in the list of Favorite tags you see when you go to the homepage, if you had the tags `c#` and `.net` but only want to see questions involving both tags, is it possible to add a third tag that is `c# & .net` or something similar that when clicked filters the questions by both tags? Not sure if this is possible but if it is not, it would be nice to be able to do it.

I know there are synonymous tags but that in this case maps `c#.net` to `c#` not to `c#` and `.net`.

Comment: Ah, very cool. Thanks very much for the info.

Comment: I made that an answer. Originally, I had posted it as a comment while I got what I wanted together for an answer. With new nav coming out, I doubt they'll make tags like that, but there will at least be a decently easy way to save searches like this.

Comment: [Same question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110268/allow-users-to-save-combinations-of-tags-as-favorites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not *exactly* what you're wanting, there are a couple ways to do this.

As an off-site workaround, at least for now, you could bookmark a search. For example, `[c#][.net] is:q` will find only questions with *both* tags. This has the added benefit of allowing you to specify other parameters for this, which you can find on [the search help page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Another, built-in method is to opt in for the New-Nav. To do this, go to your profile and click your Settings tab. From there, you want the "Preferences" option.

[image: List of menu items under settings]

Down at the very bottom of the page is the New-Nav opt-in. Click the checkmark there, and you'll be on the list to start using the New-Nav.

[image: New-Nav Opt-In]

It could take a bit of time, a couple of days, before you actually get the feature, but you'll be put on the waiting list for it as soon as you check the box. If you change your mind, you can uncheck the box to be taken off the list.

Once New-Nav is active for you, you can create a new tab. On the main question list, click the "+ new tab" button to create the tab.

[image: New Tab button]

Then enter your desired tags and make sure the "All" option is selected. Selecting "Any" will make it so you're getting questions with either of the tags.

[image: New Tab tag list]

To the right of your tag list will be a blue and white save button. Hit that, and you'll have the tab saved to your account. You'll be able to click on it from the question list whenever you want to see questions with both tags, and you can even use the sort and filter options to the left and right of the tag box to change what exactly you're seeing.

Comment: As you said, not exactly what I was after but does the same thing in essence so I am marking this as answers. Also +1 for pictures.