# Can I still add combined tags to my favorite tags, somehow?

Tags: support, bug, tag-watching

In my favorite tags I have, for a long time, had some combinations of tags, for instance: [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)+[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)+[oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop)

I thought I was able to create them by entering [tag1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1)+[tag2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag2) in the input box show when I click "edit" next to my Favorite Tags, like so:

[image]

However, that does not seem to work anymore. This simply creates individual tags. Is it still possible somehow to add combined tags to my list of Favorite Tags?

Answer (score 2):

From [Create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> ### How do I create a new tag?
>
> Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created. When
>   creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be no longer than 25 characters
> - must use the character set `a-z` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`

The + was a valid tag character. That's why it allowed it (there's no such tag in the site, however). Apparently now it isn't possible to use them, since when they get validated, it uses the + as separator in the POST request.

Comment: I see. I thought the + was deliberately allowed for the purposes of combining tags, since the + is also used in GET requests, when searching for combined tags (by clicking on a related tag, for instance), as in [this example URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+regex). I'm aware that + is normally parsed as a space, of course; I just thought StackOverflow had cleverly repurposed it as a combinator symbol. It's a pity that this doesn't work anymore. Though I just became aware of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317505), which I will give a try.

Comment: @DecentDabbler no, actually + should be parsed as part of the tag, like [tag:c++].

Comment: Ah right, of course!