# Collections for favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Once I mark a certain question to favorite, it can be due to multiple reasons:

- Might answer later
- Interesting
- Just in case I may need it in the future
- Has to do with what I am doing currently

(This doesn't mean someone has the same reasons.)

Currently I got 106 favorite questions and am now reaching a point where I'm like:

*"Yeah right, as if I'm going to look at it later... most likely going to search in Google again..."*

Simply because it's annoying to try to find them in the middle of long list.

Would it be possible to do like Instagram's photos and have collections?

Automatically once saving a picture, it saves to a collection named "All Posts", but then one can create or add to an already existing collection, like "3D Bar Charts", and "Data Science".

I'm aware of the following answers, but they are different than this one because collections are personal categories each person has for own orientation, not tags that are a guide for everyone:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317505/5675325
- [Tag combinations for Favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317501/5675325)

Comment: @yivi thank you, [this seems to be the solution](https://stackapps.com/q/8163/64722).